# How to determine maximum text length for AlertDialog buttons?

Tags: android, dialog, font-size, android-alertdialog

I got a problem with a really, really simple `AlertDialog` that creates my About dialog with three choices. Have a look at how it looks like on an emulator, my HTC Sensation and a Galaxy S2:

[image: AlertDialog on three different devices]

The dialog is created by this (pseudo) code:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
builder.setNeutralButton("Disclaimer", [...]);
builder.setNegativeButton("Jetzt zum Market", [...]);
```

It is so simple, I never thought about maximum text lengths differing so much on different devices! Plus: I think Samsung's tearing apart of "Disclaimer" is such a mess, not to talk about the whole word "Market" missing.

How am I supposed to create a simple `AlertDialog` when this already is a problem?
Any clues? Think of a device that sets such a large font that even "Cancel" does not fit any more! *sigh* How can I prevent such things?

Thanks for advices!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Drew DeNardo is almost correct.

The myDialog.getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE) is returning null because it was not been created.

You need to override onShow:

```
final AlertDialog alert= builder.create();

alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

        float textSize = 15.0f;

        Button positive = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positive.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);

        Button neutral = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        neutral.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);

        Button negative = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        negative.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's better to use TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP

Answer (score 0):

Specify the font size in a unit of "DP" (density-independent pixels).  This will instruct each phone to scale the font so that it looks (more or less) the same on all devices.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted, I can only assume you don't know how to do what I advised.  Let me provide more detail.

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
builder.setNeutralButton("Disclaimer", [...]);
builder.setNegativeButton("Jetzt zum Market", [...]);

AlertDialog myDialog = builder.create();

/* You'll have to play with this value to see what looks right */
float textSize = 15.0f;

Button positive = myDialog.getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE);
positive.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);

Button neutral = myDialog.getButton(BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
neutral.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);

Button negative = myDialog.getButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
negative.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);

myDialog.show();
```

This will make the buttons have a different font size than the title and body of your dialog.  You can replace the content view of your AlertDialog using the method found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

In the layout you create for your content set the font size to match whatever you end up with for your "textSize" variable above.  You can use units of "dp" directly in your layout.

If you have further questions please let me know what they are, don't just downvote.

Comment: Well, I tried getting the dialog buttons with exactly your approach: but always just get null! Plus: even if it worked, how would I determine the correct size so everything fits? I cannot "play" as you suggest because I do not own all available Android devices - so this, if it worked, can not be the proper way to do it. :-( But I guess I will have to go the custom way - just to get the buttons fit...

Comment: Could you please try it yourself? I never get any Button delivered with getButton() method! Always just null.